# set propotional size for uicollectionView cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

Helo all,

I have create a UIcollectionView cell.I want set the height & width propotional to all devices.For eg.If height 80 & width is 90 on iphone 5s then it should be propotional on other devices as well.I am using this method.

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return CGSizeMake(80, 90);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width/.25, self.view.frame.size.width/.28);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is multiply the dimensions of your cell by whatever proportion you desire. If 80x90 is the size you want on the iPhone 5, then calculate the appropriate multipliers by consulting a guide [like this one](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions). For example, the 5's point resolution is 320 x 568, and the 6's is 375 x 667, so your width multiplier will be 375/320, and the height one will be 667/568. (I'll let you do the math. :))

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.width/2);
-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
return 0
;}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
return 0; }
```

Comment: that makes my cell looks too big

Comment: u should use autoresizing in storyboard at your cell

Comment: I am using autolayout

Comment: oh i see, but in my project i use that and work..but i not using autolayout :D

Comment: I am using autolayout that i why i can't use your approach